# How can we validate a string consist any single alphabets or not in scala?

Tags: scala

My application takes in a string like this:

- `k0qVsfpz7_cG9n75OjZCCA`
- `P700058213111115432196`
- `1700058213111115432196`

I need to validate in a Scala script that the string consists of any single alphabet or not.

Comment: What do you mean by *alphabet* only numbers, only ASCII characters or only characters of a language specific alphabet? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I meant to say input is coming like "P700058213111115432196" so here 1 alphabet P is there and input "1700058213111115432196" is having no alphabets, so if any alphabet is inside that input , i need to raise a flag based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `exists` method over a given string, which maps each character onto a predicate provided. For instance, `Char.isLetter` proves true only if a given character is an alphabetical value (a letter). Hence

```
"P700058213111115432196".exists(_.isLetter)
Boolean = true
```

and

```
"700058213111115432196".exists(_.isLetter)
Boolean = false
```

Similarly with `forall` we can verify that each and every character in a string holds a predicate, for instance

```
"P700058213111115432196".forall(_.isDigit)
Boolean = false
```

and

```
"700058213111115432196".forall(_.isDigit)
Boolean = true
```

To remark that both `exists` and `forall` iterate over a collection. Here we iterate over a Scala string which is treated as a sequence of `Char`.